# Issue with starting MySQL in XAMPP control panel

Tags: mysql, xampp

With no luck, I am trying to get MySQL to start in the XAMPP control panel. When I try to get it to work, I get the following output:

```
13:28:19  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:28:19  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:28:19  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:28:19  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:28:19  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:28:20  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:28:20  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

And then, the error log outputs the following:

```
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220729 13:26:49
2022-07-29 13:26:49 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11451
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-07-29 13:28:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-07-29 13:28:18 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have already tried a couple of suggestions that I have come across on StackOverflow but nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306*

Comment: I have also checked to see if port 3306 is open and it appears to be

Comment: Looks like there is already a mysqld runing. So stop the old one and start the new one

Comment: is because is there something installed on services and use the same port and maybe is running or an anvirus keeps blocked that port (maybe same mysql running and remain locked somehow for an error) so check services.msc in cmd or task manager too

Answer (score 0):

I got also such kind of error during connecting mysql in xampp, there fore to fix the error you should change the port other wise uninstall if there is mysql server installed in your machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).